# What does FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS do?

Tags: file, winapi, createfile

I'm aware that [`FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858.aspx) allows for case sensitivity in file names, but the fact that it wasn't named `FILE_FLAG_CASE_SENSITIVE` makes me think it might be doing more than that.

Does it do anything else, or am I analyzing this too deeply?

Comment: For a 32bit flag on an core API - CreateFile which is about file which is almost everything about IO, each bit is so important that the team  need a lot of think to decide. Obviously finally they decide it to be FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS , maybe at first it is FILE_FLAG_CASE_SENSITIVE. Maybe Bill Gates participates this too you can email him to check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, it only gives case sensitivity. I suspect they originally named it that way because they were as uncertain as the rest of us whether supporting POSIX semantics might involve *something* more than case sensitivity. This way if it turned out they needed to do more, they could just fix the bug in their implementation of POSIX semantics rather than requiring a fundamental change in the specification.

Comment: A * is valid character in a file name on Unix.  And others.

Comment: @Hans: True, but that's not required by POSIX (which specifies a few restrictions on file names, and allows an implementation to impose more -- which Windows does, so even with FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS, attempting to create a file with "*" in the name will fail).

Comment: You do have to set the time machine back to 1992.